# confused with URL parameter in jinja Django

Tags: html, django, url, hyperlink, jinja2

I confused with my URL in jinja:
my url.py is:

```
 path('<int:listing_id>', views.listing, name='listing')
```

views.py:

```
def listing(request, listing_id):
return render(request, 'listings/listing.html')
```

I get an integer in url as an id to specify list(listing_id)
but I understand in my html file I must write listing.id instead of listing_id

```
<a href="{% url 'listing' listing.id %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">More Info</a>
```

My question is why I must use . instead of _ (listing.id instead of listing_id)

Answer (score 0):

With `listing.id` you specify the *value* to pass as parameter. You can make it more verbose by writing:

```
"{% url 'listing' listing_id=listing.id %}"
```

The left part of the expression, the `listing_id=` thus specifies the name of the URL parameter whereas the right part,the `=listing.id` specifies what value we will fill in for that URL pattern.

`listing` is likely an object that you passed when rendering the object. If you write `listing_id`, the render engine will look for a object you passed to the `context`, but there is no such item, `listing.id` will use the `.id` attribute of the `listing` object you passed to te context.